# pyqgis: displaying 2 different datasets in one instance

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a need to display 2 completely different sets of spatial data in a single standalone qgis application. This means, 2 separate sets of layers, 2 map canvases, etc. Is this at all possible? (since some of the core objects in a qgis application are singletons, ie. QgsMapLayerRegistry)

Comment: Didn't know about that, is there a reward in cash? ;) Or maybe some super godlike priviledges on the site? ;)

Comment: No u just won a week's holiday in Hawaii ... :-)

Comment: I don't like or need vacation, i've too much work.

Comment: For multiple map canvases, you could check the [source code](https://github.com/faunalia/dockablemirrormap) for the **Dockable Mirrormap** plugin.

Comment: Ok, i ll check it out

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after tinkering with different ideas and solutions i came up with a very simple one. What seemed as a limitiation to achieving what i wanted, actually wasn't. You can have as many QgsMapCanvases in an single instance application as you need. Second fact is, yes, all layers have to re registered in the QgsMapRegistry instance, even if they are completely unrelated, but when you want to display the data, you can selectively send (MAP!)layer sets to canvases vvia setLayerSet method as usual.